# The equivalent function to 'cumsum' for "difftime" objects in R

Tags: r

What is the equivalent function to 'cumsum' for "difftime" objects in R ?

sectionDuration is a difftime object

```
cumSectionDuration = cumsum(sectionDuration)
```

give an error

Comment: Can you include a minimal example dataset using the `dput` function?

Comment: You can use `cumsum(as.numeric(sectionDuration))`

Comment: It works ! Thank you, but the function Reduce is more efficient

Answer (score 3):

Please consider the usage of `Reduce` function.
You will not lose the type like in the `as.numeric` solution.

```r
a <- difftime(Sys.time(), Sys.time())
b <- difftime(Sys.time(), Sys.time())
# ERROR cumsum(c(a, b))
# 'cumsum' not defined for "difftime" objects
Reduce("+", c(a, b))
#> Time difference of -9.059906e-06 secs
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>